# Целое значение устанавливает количество выводимых строк с символом

Tags: c, функции

Напишите функцию, которая принимает три аргумента: символ и два целых числа.
Символ предназначен для вывода. Первое целое значение задает количество
указанных символов в строке, а второе целое число устанавливает количество
таких строк. Напишите программу, в которой используется эта функция.

В функции у меня не получается сделать так, что бы второе целое число(в даном случае b) устанавливало количество строк c вводимым символом.

```
void func(char ch, int a, int b){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<a; i++){
        printf("%c", ch);
    }

    
}
```

Comment: [вложенные циклы](https://labs-org.ru/c-2_2/#i-2)

Comment: Помогли. Спасибо!;)